# Assign a value to hidden field in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi I am trying to assign the value from a select input to a hidden field using jquery, although I keep receiving an invalid left hand side of operator. I tried using the hiddenProgramIds.ClientId, but only received an error. Can someone shed a little light. Thanks.

```
$("#programSelector").on('click', function addProgram() {
    $("<%= hiddenProgramIds %>").val() = $('#programSelector').val();
});
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenProgramIds" runat="server" Value="" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't set a value with `=` in jQuery, you pass the string as an argument to the `val()` function, like this

```
$("#programSelector").on('change', function() {
    $("#<%= hiddenProgramIds.ClientID %>").val( this.value );
});
```

and if #programSelector is in fact a select element, you should be using the `change` event, not `click`

Comment: +1 I was actually starring at the code to know what's wrong.. :)

Comment: @Bharadwaj - That's probably right, ASP isn't my thing but I would assume you'd have to use ClientID to output the ID, but I left the ASP intact as it's not clear if the ID is wrong or not, but you would have to add the # either way.

Answer (score 1):

You need use ClientId to JQuery works

```
 $("#<%= hiddenProgramIds.ClientID %>").val( this.value );
```